# How can I use special character (?) in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have developed a website using Raw PHP. I have used special character (? and ~) in URL. Example:  http://webdeveloperszone.com/?~=portfolio .

Now, I want to rebuild this website using wordpress or codeigniter. I want to keep all the existing link live, because google has cached those links. That means, I have to create links which supports special character (? and ~).

Can any one tell me how can I do this?

Comment: i suggest you to buid website in word press and provide 301 redirection to all old URL to new created URL by wordpress plugin:https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
string urlencode ( string $str );
string urldecode ( string $str );
```

**JavaScript**

```
encodeURI(uri);
decodeURI(encodeURI(uri));
```

Answer (score 0):

For codeigniter

Have a look on

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Enable query string

And change

```
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
```

To

```
$config['controller_trigger'] = '~';
```

Comment: Showing "Disallowed Key Characters."

Comment: Keep above setting and find the file "system/core/Input.php"


On line no. 668

`$_GET[$this->_clean_input_keys($key)] = $this->_clean_input_data($val);`

Replace with 

`if($key!='~')
 $_GET[$this->_clean_input_keys($key)] = $this->_clean_input_data($val);`

And try it again

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable suggestion. It's done now, but little tense about changing the core file.

Answer (score 0):

In  wordpress just you need to create page.
and then change post name from database as you like.

Create page named portfolio.

save and publish it.

then go to phpmyadmin.

open wp_posts.

get the record for perticular page.
and change post_name to your slug ?~=portfolio.

That's it.